# Javascript placed input element is over other elements in page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with a css-made dropdown menu that appear on `:hover` some links. It works fine but if I place an `input` element in the page via javascript it is always over the dropdown menu, no matter what `z-index` I set in the menu.

Is there a way to place dinamically the `input` in the page in a way that is behind the menu as normal inputs does?

Thanks

Here is the code I use to add the input (probably not the best code in the world but it works for me). `Tools` is a little helper object containing some functions

```
    var sels = null == arguments[0] ? document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=dinamiclist]'): document.querySelectorAll(arguments[0]);
for ( var i in sels ) {
    if ( isNaN(i) ) continue;
    setup(sels[i]);
}

function setup() {
    var e = arguments[0],
        S = e.tagName == 'select' ? true: false,
        t = document.createElement('input'),
        c = document.createElement('div'),
        l = document.createElement('ol'),
        sel = S ? e.selectedIndex || 0: e.value,
        ctrl = false,
        ctrlString = '',
        sall = false,
        durl = S ? '': e.getAttribute('data-url'),
        exp = e.hasAttribute('data-expar') ? e.getAttribute('data-expar'): false,
        plch = e.hasAttribute('placeholder') ? e.getAttribute('placeholder'): 'Ricerca',
        delayTimer
    ;

    if ( !S && ! e.hasAttribute('data-nodelprev') ) Tools.prev(e).style.display = 'none';
    c.setAttribute('class', 'dinamic-list');
    t.type = 'text';
    t.setAttribute('data-name', e.name);
    t.setAttribute('placeholder', plch);
    if ( e.hasAttribute('size') ) t.setAttribute('size', e.getAttribute('size'));
    t.addEventListener('keydown', find, true);
    t.addEventListener('keyup', find, true);
    t.value = S ? e.options[sel].text: e.hasAttribute('data-show') ? e.getAttribute('data-show'): e.value;
    c.appendChild(t);
    c.appendChild(l);
    Tools.parent(e).insertBefore(c, e);
    e.style.display = 'none';
    e.setAttribute('tabindex', '10000');
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would also help if you provided an example of your code.

Comment: So far the only thing I've tried is cloning the menu, remove it from the page and put it back after the input is added but with no success. I will try to add the code I use to add the input in the page

Comment: Is there any html/css you could add as a snippet to help us see the DOM layout etc?

Comment: I found out the problem but still have no solution. The menu container is setted position: sticky; and the input container is setted position: relative. now if I set the menu to position relative or if I remove the position relative from the input container everything works fine but with the needed css the menu goes below the input